# Form Submission = AdWords Conversion

Tags: php, google-ads-api

After an html form submission I need to record an AdWords conversion. The get_support.html calls contact.php. Here's the form portion of the code:

```
    <form method="post" action="contact.php">
    <div class="field">
        <label>WHAT DO YOU NEED HELP WITH?: <span>*</span></label>
        <textarea name="message" class="text textarea" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>NAME: <span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>PHONE NUMBER: <span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" class="text" />
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label>EMAIL: <span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="text" />
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <input type="button" id="send" value="SUBMIT INFO" />
        <div class="loading"></div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Here's contact.php

```
    <?php
//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$message = ($_GET['message']) ?$_GET['message'] : $_POST['message'];

//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1
if ($_POST) $post=1;

//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your telephone.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.'; 
if (!$message) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your message.'; 

//if the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {

    // ====== Your mail here  ====== //
    $to = 'US TECH SUPPORT <ustechsupport@techsupportheroes.com>';  
    //sender
    $from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

    //subject and the html message
    $subject = 'FORM-SUBMISSION-VIRUSREMOVALHEROES.COM';    
    $message = '
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Phone:</td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email:</td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Message:</td><td>' . nl2br($message) . '</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>';

    //send the mail
    $result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

    //if POST was used, display the message straight away
    if ($_POST) {
        if ($result) echo 'Help is on the way! We have received your message.';
        else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

    //else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
    //ajax script can react accordingly
    //1 means success, 0 means failed
    } else {
        echo $result;   
    }

//if the errors array has values
} else {}


//Simple mail function with HTML header
function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    if ($result) return 1;

    else return 0;  
}

?>
```

And the conversion code from Google for my Form Fill

```
echo '<!-- Google Code for Form Submission Conversion Page --> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
/* <![CDATA[ */ 
var google_conversion_id = 1004137309; 
var google_conversion_language = "en"; 
var google_conversion_format = "3"; 
var google_conversion_color = "ffffff"; 
var google_conversion_label = "H1HvCNOWswQQ3dbn3gM"; 
var google_conversion_value = 0; 
/* ]]> */ 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js&amp;quot;&amp;gt; 
</script> 
<noscript> 
<div style="display:inline;"> 
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1004137309/?value=0&amp;amp;amp;label=H1HvCNOWswQQ3dbn3gM&amp;amp;amp;guid=ON&amp;amp;amp;script=0&amp;quot;/&amp;gt; 
</div> 
</noscript>';
```

I have researched this and just cannot figure out how to solve the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like it ought to be echo'd when the script confirms there are no errors?

Comment: Where should place the echo? Wherever I place the Google Conversion code, I get the error from contact.php Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later

Comment: Is the conversion code exactly what came out of Google? Your close brackets appear to have been converted to `&amp;quot;&amp;gt;`

Answer (score 0):

Google Adwords conversion code works by placing the conversion tracking code on the "Thank You" page. Once your form is submitted, lead the user to a Thank You page. Place your conversion tracking code in the source of this page and you will start registering conversions. As the only logical way of users reaching this page is by submitting a duly filled contact form.

Also, make sure there is no other way to get to this page except by submitting the form (using robots and de-linking from every other page on-site)

Comment: Good option, but you would need specific thank you page for each form in the site.

Comment: Not necessarily, you could add embedded identifiers in your submit links (utm, etc) to know which form from which page the user has been referred. If not, your thank you page analytics will anyway show the page trail and tell you which page the user has come from.